# unindent does not match any outer indentation level on pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame as py
py.init()

win = py.display.set_mode((500, 500))

py.display.set_caption("Lolgame")

srnlen = 500
x = 240
y = 200
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 6

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
run = True
while run:
    py.time.delay(35)
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = py.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[py.K_LEFT] and x >= vel:
       x -= vel
    if keys[py.K_RIGHT] and x < srnlen - width - vel:
       x += vel
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[py.K_UP] and y >= vel:
           y -= vel
        if keys[py.K_DOWN] and y < srnlen - height - vel:
           y += vel
        if keys[py.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
           y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
           
           jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    py.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    print(x, y)
    
    py.display.update()
    
    
py.quit()
```

The error is in line 42 saying (unindent does not match any outer indentation level)
not sure why its happening please i am VERY STUCK HELP me (just writing some random words because the system says that my description has to be bigger lol)

Comment: Show us the full error message. I'm not going to count the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on line 42 (and 44) the are 11 spaces of indentation, when it looks like 12 is required. To fix this you'll need to click somewhere in that indentation (on lines 42 and 44) and press the space bar.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation spaces are wrong buddy. Instead of using 4 spaces and counting them each time use "TAB", it will auto-indent the line to 4 spaces. There will be no indentation mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

In line 42 (`y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg`) you need one more space before `y` and in line 44 (`jumpCount -= 1`) you need one more space before `jumpCount`. It will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i dnnwloaded and run your code. This code throw an exception because line 42 and 44 have 11 white-spaces of indentation and *this lines must have 12 spaces*.

```py
import pygame as py
py.init()

win = py.display.set_mode((500, 500))

py.display.set_caption("Lolgame")

srnlen = 500
x = 240
y = 200
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 6

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
run = True
while run:
    py.time.delay(35)
    for event in py.event.get():
        if event.type == py.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = py.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[py.K_LEFT] and x >= vel:
       x -= vel
    if keys[py.K_RIGHT] and x < srnlen - width - vel:
       x += vel
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[py.K_UP] and y >= vel:
           y -= vel
        if keys[py.K_DOWN] and y < srnlen - height - vel:
           y += vel
        if keys[py.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            
            # ERROR FIXED USING 12 white spaces of indentation
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    py.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    print(x, y)
    
    py.display.update()
    
    
py.quit()
```